# geolocation doesn't work on some phones, permission granted

Tags: android, geolocation

I'm currently facing an issue with some of the users of my app. For some reasons, on some phones (mostly Samsung, on Android 6.0 and 7.0) the geolocation isn't working.
The permissions are granted, gps is active but it simply doesn't work.

Does anybody have a clue on the problem ? It works fine on most phones though, that's why i don't get the problem.

Thank you for your time.

Below are some code sample where the geolocation is handled, even if i don't think the problem is from here.

```
        int result2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    int result3 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

    return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && result2 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result3 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
```

This one is on the fragment where the location is needed. It's supposed to be granted before that, it's more like a safety check.

```
//  Else, alert user and try again
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "location is null");
        prepareView(State.NoGeolocation);

        // In case there's no Geolocation check if the user gave the proper permissions
        // to the App. If not given, then a dialog will popup and ask the user for them.
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            return;
        }

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getPotentialFriends();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```